# how to make the tabindex go to the close button in the form

Tags: vb.net, forms, accessibility

I have been asked by my company to make my vb.net app friendly to those who use accessibility features, like keyboard, narrator, etc...

I have noticed that when using tab in the keyboard, the focus do not go to the close button in the form. Is there a way to make sure when some one is using the tab to go to the close button?

Comment: With `forms`, do you mean Windows Forms? If so, probably because you usually set the `CancelButton` of a Form to the Close Button, so when you press `ESC` the Form closes. The `TAB` key is used to move the focus to the next (or previous) Control.

Comment: BTW, if my assumption about Windows Forms is correct, replace `forms` with `winforms`.

Comment: Are you talking about the Close button on the title bar of the form? If so then that's standard Windows behaviour. That button is linked to the Alt+F4 key combination. That button is not part of the client area of your form so Tabbing to it won't work. If you want to be able to Tab to a Close button then add a `Button` control to your form.

Comment: Yeah i am talking about windows forms, and yes I am talking about the close button in the title bar.. @John thank you for your input.. That makes sense

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trigger the system dialog through the keyboard you can check for a TAB key press on the control in question and then use SendKeys to pop the dialog open.

```
  Private Sub TextBox2_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.PreviewKeyDown
      If e.KeyCode = 9 Then
          SendKeys.Send("% ")
      End If
  End Sub
```